# bounding the function from below.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus

Suppose that $n \in (0,2]$, $f$ is Holder continuous with exponent $\alpha \in (0,1)$, i.e., $\|f\|_{C^{0,\alpha}} = \sup \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{\|x - y\|^{\alpha}} < \infty$, and $g \in L^\infty(B_1)$.
How can I bound this function from below $f(x)|D_x g(x,y)|^n - f(y)|D_y g(x,y)|^n$?

My attempt:
Note that, $|x-y|\geq ||x|-|y||$, so:
$f(x)|D_x g(x,y)|^n - f(y)|D_y g(x,y)|^n\geq ||f(x)|D_x g(x,y)|^n|-|f(y)|D_y g(x,y)|^n||$

Should I consider whether $n$ is in the interval $(0,1)$ or $(1,2]$?

Thank you!